# Python: convert HTML string to HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am scraping a page with `infinite scroll`. When my `scrapy` spider hits the page and it returns some json like this:

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "num_items": 30,
    "content": "<div data-doc_id=\"1234\" class=\"item_cell has_cover lazy_images\" dir=\"auto\">...."
}
```

So the HTML of the page is in returns as a string with some escape character. Now I want to scrape this string. How do I convert it back to HTML?

Comment: _Now I want to scrape this string. How do I convert it back to HTML?_ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

html_response = HtmlResponse(body=your_json['content'])

# and then
html_response.css('div.item_cell::attr(whatever)').get()
```

Good luck.

Comment: Or use `parsel.Selector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLParser`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.feed

or you can use `BeautifulSoup` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response['content'])
```